# How to identify webelements in selenium that in iframe with javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe

[image]I am trying to automate for wiki page using selenium WebDriver. I am not able to identify webelements that under iframe using

```
dri.switchTo.frame(frameid);
```

because of iframe is as below:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" data-synchrony="true" id="wysiwygTextarea_ifr" src="javascript:&quot;&quot;" allowtransparency="true" title="{#aria.rich_text_area}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;" tabindex="100" class=""></iframe>
```

I have create wiki page with table manually. Now i want to update values in table using selenium.

can you please guide me how to identify the table under iframe.

Comment: Can you give more context? Include a [mcve]?

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Comment: Java language is used.

Comment: *Java language is used.*... If so why question marked with **JavaScript** tag?

Comment: Yes tag Java as language used

Comment: Update the question with some more _outerHTML_ above the `<iframe>` tag

Answer (score 0):

[image]try this code for switching the control of webDriver object to iframe.

```
driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id*='Textarea']")));
```

If table is inside the iframe , then after switching the control you can interacts with table elements.

try out this code and let me know the status

Comment: Hi cruisepandey
Yes i tried with the above, its not working.

Comment: yes for interacting with table after switching control : use this code :  driver.findElement(by.cssSelector("table[class^='relative table']"));

Comment: after switching what do you wanna do ?

Comment: After switch to frame i want to edit cells in the table. i tried with the below code:
dri.switchTo().frame("wysiwygTextarea_ifr");
    dri.findElement(By.className("relative-table confluenceTable wrapped")).isDisplayed();
Table itself not identifying.

Comment: for that you have to write locators(cssSelector , Xpath , className ,ID , value , linkText , etc ) for respective cell and then you can interacts with those element.

Comment: Use this code : dri.switchTo.frame(dri.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id*='Textarea']"))); boolean visibilty =   dri(findElement(by.cssSelector("table[class^='relative table con']"))).isDisplayed();  System.out.println(visibilty);

Comment: In console you should get true as output

Comment: It is not returns true

Comment: what was the output ?

Comment: false. Throwing no such element exception

Comment: No its internal purpose we are using